# Can I use Camel Simple Expression inside JsonPath Language?

Tags: apache-camel, jsonpath

Hi I would like to use a header value from my camel exchange as a filter condition within my JsonPath expression.

Somethink like this:

```
.setBody().jsonpath("$.person[?(@.role=='${headers.role}')]")
```

The simple expression will not be resolved this way.

How can I get this done with Apache Camel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered one way to get it done with a processor component and some Java Code:

```java
String jsonpathFilter = SimpleLanguage.simple(
  "$.person[?(@.role=='${headers.role}')]").evaluate(exchange, String.class);
String result = new JsonPathExpression(jsonpathFilter).evaluate(exchange, String.class);
exchange.getIn().setBody(result);
```

But I'm not so happy with this solution. So if you know any better way, please let me know.

Comment: Gotcha - your own solution is in that case preferred until CAMEL-10189
 has been resolved (which is more or less doing to do the same as you are) .  I removed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible directly in the syntax, but its a good idea. So I have logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10189

If we have this out of the box then it works for any DSL such as Java and XML DSL.

Comment: Thanks, that would make it easier in the future.